# MSMQ private queue size limit

Tags: windows-7, c#-4.0, msmq, netmsmqbinding

I am trying to put messages in a private queue defined on my local computer, but the queue size cannot exceed 8 MB. I am getting an exception every time after that size is reached. The size for the specific queue is set at 10 GB. I am running Windows 7 Professional. Is there a limitation because of that?

Comment: The problem seems more like being unable to put messages greater than 3 MB on the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/08/22/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages.aspx

This clears the issue as MSMQ limitation. One cannot place messages more than 4MB on the queue. That means that for my application, I have to pass the message identifier through the queue and store the message itself somewhere else.